# Rotate and save image in Titanium?

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy, image-rotation

I am currently working on an android app that allow user to rotate the image then save it. I am able to save the image but when I check it, it doesn't rotate. Would appreciate if someone can point me to a right direction.

Here is my code:

```
_rotateLeft.addEventListener('click', function(e){
            _rotationDegree = _rotationDegree - 90;
            var t = Ti.UI.create2DMatrix();
            //t.rotate(90);
            //imageContainer.transform = t;

            imageContainer.animate({
                transform: t.rotate(_rotationDegree)
            });
        });

_saveButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var imgSave = imageView.toImage();
    var moment          = require('alloy/moment');

    var directory = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.externalStorageDirectory, 'images/test');
    !directory.exists() && directory.createDirectory();

    var fileName        = String.format('rotate_%s.jpg', moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD-HH-mm'));
    var file            = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(directory.resolve(), fileName);
    var fileNativePath  = file.nativePath;
    // Write media to file
    //file.write(newBlob);
    file.write(imgSave);

    Ti.API.info('New Save File : ' + JSON.stringify(file));

    imageView.setImage(file);

});
```

Here is my view:

```
<View id="imageContainer">
        <!--<View id="imageUploadedView"></View>-->
        <ImageView id="imageView"></ImageView>
    </View>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things I found odd in your code:

1 - You are rotating **imageContainer** and then you are capturing **imageView.toImage();** which I think is the cause of issue because:

- Rotating container view rotates the child elements also, and capturing a **child.toImage();** will return you the UI of that child irrespective of the rotation (though I am not 100% sure because I would prefer below step to do this task).
- So to make to properly work, rotate **imageView** and use **imageContainer.toImage();** so that child view is rotated and parent view can save its rotated state.

2 - Inside ***_saveButton*** click event, use this line:
`imageView.setImage(file.read());` because you were not reading the blob data of the file in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the transform first then apply the transform to the view before saving.

```
_rotateLeft.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  var rotateTransform = Ti.UI.create2DMatrix({ 
  rotate: 45 
  });

imageContainer.transform = rotateTransform;
}
```

Reference: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.2DMatrix